# Generate a encoded string for a string input

Tags: java

I have a requirement to implement a method, which when takes a **String** as an argument returns a unique String for it.

Example :

```
Source String = "abc"
```

Output - An encoded String for `abc - say , xyz.`

And everytime the method needs to return xyz for abc.

Please provide some suggestions on the same.

I tried encryption and encoding mechanisms, but the problem with this is the length of the encoded string exceeds beyond a limit.

Ex : String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopq"

I want to map this string to another string of 8 characters. I am looking for an algorithm for this convertion.

Comment: Are you asking about encryption and decryption ?

Comment: Same question, do you have some security requirements, or any string is valuable, provided it is unique ?

Comment: are you asking for a BASE64 decode/encode?

Comment: There is not security feature involved in it. Since we use a client server application and there is a restriction in the length of the string , we were planning to cut down the length of the string to a 8 character string. The client also needs to know this modified string

Comment: The client should also be able to generate the corresponding encoded string for a given input string.

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the unique strings in a class variable that is a Map.
2. Try looking up the argument string's unique code in the Map.
3. If it doesn't exist, shift all character codes by 1.  Enter the string's unique string in the Map.
4. Return the unique string.

Comment: But does this guarentee that each string would have a unique code?

Comment: Okay, don't shift the character codes by 1, and make each string's unique string be the string itself.  Does that guarantee that each string will have a unique code?

Comment: The main purpose of this requirement is to reduce the number of characters in the request parameter from my client. So i need a mapping between the original request parameter string and a unique reduced string